# Define the linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ by $T(v) = Av$. Find the dimensions of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$.

Tags: linear-transformations

> Define the linear transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ by $T(v) = Av$. Find the dimensions of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$.
> $$ A=\begin{bmatrix}
>      0 & 1 \\
>      1 & 4 \\
>      3 & 1 \\
>      5 & -1 \\
>      0 & -2 \\
>      0 & 1 
>     \end{bmatrix} $$

> dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n = $ ?

> dimension of $\mathbb{R}^m = $ ?

I've asked this question where I can clearly see that the matrix $A$ is of order $6×2$ which tells me that for $Av$ to be valid $v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ must be of order $2×1$. And the result. $Av$ gives a $6×1$ column matrix, which is in $\mathbb{R}^m$. From this two information I can say that dimension of $\mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathbb{R}^m$ are $2$ and $6$ respectively.

Now my question is how can I write the answer in a more formal way? I want to answer it in a way as if I'm writing it on an exam. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

Your reasoning is formal enough. I will elaborate below. Meanwhile, you can also note that the matrix associated with a linear transformation $T:\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R^m$ is $m\times n$ in size, i.e. it is an element of $M_{m\times n}(\Bbb R)$.

---

$A$ is $6\times 2$ matrix. Assuming that vectors in the Euclidean space $\Bbb R^n$ are written as $n\times 1$ **column** vectors, we get $n = 2$ and $m = 6$. Why?

$\Bbb R^n$ consists of $n\times 1$ vectors, which are pre-multiplied by $A \in M_{6\times 2}(\Bbb R)$ to give $m\times 1$ vectors. For $A$ and $v\in \Bbb R^n$ (represented by an $n\times 1$ matrix) to be compatible for matrix-multiplication, we must have $n = 2$. Further, the product of a $6\times 2$ matrix with a $2\times 1$ matrix yields a $6\times 1$ matrix, which can be viewed as an element of $\Bbb R^6$. Thus, $m = 6$.